# animation works only one div not all

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing some experiments and i have this code now, i have a class that is added dynamically to all of my 3 containers whenever the button clicked.

The class is added successfully to all divs but only one div that is animated!!

```js
const hamburgers = [...document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburgers.forEach(hamburger => {
        if(!hamburger.classList.contains('move'))  hamburger.classList.add('move') ;
        else hamburger.classList.remove('move')
    })
})
```

```css
.hamburger {
    position: relative;
}

.bar {
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height:5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(1) {
    top:50px;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 100px;
}

 .bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 150px;
} 

#hamburger-1 {
    left: 500px;
    background: #eee;
}

#hamburger-3 {
    left: 700px;
} 

.move {
    left: -150%;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger" id="hamburger-1">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger-2">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div  class="hamburger" id="hamburger-3">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn">click</button>
```

**Why** `left:-150%` **only work for one div and not the others when click the button??**

Comment: ok, the issue is specificity .. ID will always win .. and only one element (the second) don't have an ID in the CSS file, so this one work fine

Comment: The three divs are the same class, id, even children, one works and other not, and if it works for one it should work for all

Comment: check your CSS code, you are adding left to only 2 element using ID selector, those one aren't working because ID is more specific than class. So they are different for the working one

Comment: Your .move class is to weak. You can add the IDs like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/51rjsdct/)

Comment: i know about css specifity but this one tricked my mind, thank you you can add your answer so i can accept it.